# Is it possible to rotate just the atoms of a molecule in chemfig?

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

In the first picture there is a regular molecule made with chemfig. [image: first image]

Could it be possible to rotate just the atoms as shown in the second image?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the code of this molecule so that we can try things out?

Comment: The chance to answer here is reduced because you don't provide the code from which we can start with experimenting. I.e. MWE which produces the first picture. You cannot expect that we will start with reading the chemfig manual and create such example manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\rotatebox{-90}{
    \chemfig{
        CN-[:265,,1]*6(-=-(-N*6(--*6(=-(-N*5(-(=O)-=-(=O)-))=-=)--O--))=-=)
    }
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately, this code does not work correctly.

```
\setchemfig{atom style={rotate=-90}}
```

but node style works perfectly

```
\chemfig[node style={rotate=-90}]{
    CN-[:175,,1]*6(-=-(-N*6(--*6(=-(-N*5(-(=O)-=-(=O)-))=-=)--O--))=-=)
}
```